# how to exclude all properties of one interface from another?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two interfaces, for example:

```
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}


interface B {
  b: string;
}
```

I want to create a type that has all the keys of A while excluding all the keys of B that A has too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Omit` type suggested in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html), combined with `keyof`:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>; 

type C = Omit<A, keyof B>;
```

Now anything of type `C` can't have the property `b` from your example, or anything else that both `A` and `B` have.

Comment: Or a more direct version `type Diff<A, B> = Pick<A, Exclude<keyof A, keyof B>>;` :)