# Cut interface or type props from object

Tags: typescript

I have two Interfaces:

```js
interface Needed {
    intVal: number;
    stringVal: string;
}

interface NotNeeded {
    intVal: number;
    stringVal: string;
}
```

And object:

```js
const obj = {
    intVal: 0,
    stringVal: 'string',
    boolVal: true,
}
```

So I want to cut `NotNeeded`'s properties from `obj` and obtain such an object as a result:

```js
const resultObj = {
    intVal: 0,
    stringVal: 'string'
}
```

Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Do you want an interface as a result like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740277/how-to-exclude-all-properties-of-one-interface-from-another#51740278? Or an object?

Comment: @BrendanOtherwhyz , I need an object as a result.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. Typescript compiles to javascript and in that process the types are lost, therefore not available at runtime. There might be libraries that can help you so this, Ajv has a schema validation which can remove properties not in the schema but then there is more work involved to get this going...

Comment: Generation json schema for use in ajv https://github.com/vega/ts-json-schema-generator

Comment: Removing additional properties using ajv https://ajv.js.org/guide/modifying-data.html